# Money Type enum

Tags: c#, enums

Class Coin has the following properties: `MoneyType, Value, Diameter`.

MoneyType is enum:

```
enum CoinType
    {
        Cent,
        Nickel,
        Dime,
        QuarterDollar,
        HalfDollar,
        Dollar,        
    }
```

Each MoneyType should have specific Value and Diameter, for example Cent: Value = 1 and Diameter = 19, so if I assign MoneyType, Value and Diameter should be assigned automatically according to MoneyType. Not sure how to do this. Maybe some kind of enum tuples?

For example:

```
enum CoinType
        {
            (Cent, 1, 19),
            (Nickel, 10, 21),
.....            
        }
```

I just want that every MoneyType has specific Value and Diameter.

Comment: I think the title should be "How to implement a custom enum", just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way you can do it is by implementing your custom enum.
Source is modified according to your needs.

```
#region Base Abstract Class

public abstract class EnumBaseType<T> where T : EnumBaseType<T>
{
    protected static List<T> enumValues = new List<T>();

    public readonly string Key;
    public readonly int Value;
    public readonly int Diameter;

    public EnumBaseType(string key, int value, int diameter)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
        Diameter = diameter;
        enumValues.Add((T)this);
    }

    protected static System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T> GetBaseValues()
    {
        return enumValues.AsReadOnly();
    }

    protected static T GetBaseByKey(string key)
    {
        foreach (T t in enumValues)
        {
            if (t.Key == key) return t;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

#endregion

#region Enhanced Enum Sample

public class MoneyType : EnumBaseType<MoneyType>
{
    public static readonly MoneyType Cent = new MoneyType("Cent", 1, 19);
    public static readonly MoneyType Nickel = new MoneyType("Nickel", 5, 25);
    public static readonly MoneyType Dime = new MoneyType("Dime", 10, 30);
    public static readonly MoneyType QuarterDollar = new MoneyType("QuarterDollar", 25, 15);
    public static readonly MoneyType HalfDollar = new MoneyType("HalfDollar", 50, 100);
    public static readonly MoneyType Dollar = new MoneyType("Dollar", 100, 29);

    public MoneyType(string key, int value, int diameter)
        : base(key, value, diameter)
    {
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<MoneyType> GetValues()
    {
        return GetBaseValues();
    }

    public static MoneyType GetByKey(string key)
    {
        return GetBaseByKey(key);
    }
}

#endregion


public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        foreach (MoneyType rating in MoneyType.GetValues())
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}", rating.Key, rating.Value);

            if (rating == MoneyType.Dollar)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("This is a dollar!");
            }
        }

        foreach (MoneyType rating in MoneyType.GetValues())
        {
            if (rating.Diameter == MoneyType.Nickel.Diameter)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("This is a Nickel diameter!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20805/Enhancing-C-Enums)

**EDIT:**

Just found this: [Type-safe-enum pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html)

Comment: maybe, should think about it

Comment: I think I'll use this method

Answer (score 1):

An enum is nothing more than an INT value with a name. It stores only one discrete value. What you want to use is a class.

UPDATE:

Sorry, about my mistake. It's actually been quite awhile since I've used C#. To make it up I've written out what I mean:

```
enum CoinType {
    Cent=1,
    Nickel=5,
    Dime=10,
    QuarterDollar=25,
    HalfDollar=50,
    Dollar=100,
}

class Coin {
    public CoinType type;

    public int Diameter { 
        get { 
            switch (type) {
                case CoinType.Cent: return 19;
                case CoinType.Nickel: return 25;
                case CoinType.Dime: return 20;
                case CoinType.QuarterDollar: return 40;
                case CoinType.HalfDollar: return 40;
                case CoinType.Dollar: return 40;
            }
            return 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have Class Coin and MoneyType is one of his properties.

Comment: I know that C# has structs.

Comment: @Alex then you question is complete mess, please work on it, I can't see an Coin class or MoneyType there and exact question

Comment: for Value it makes sense, but for Diameter, I thought maybe some other way exist, for example include this value to enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom attributes onto the enum members.

```
enum CoinType
{
    [Value=1]
    [Diameter=19]
    Cent,

    ...
}
```

You can then use reflection to get the info from the attributes.

Comment: it's interesting, will think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a mapping from CoinType to diameter and another from CoinType to value. Both can be done with a simple switch statement.

```
enum CoinType
{
    Cent,
    Nickel,
    Dime,
    QuarterDollar,
    HalfDollar,
    Dollar,  
}

static class CoinTypeExts
{
    static double Diameter(this CoinType coinType)
    {
        switch (coinType)
        {
            case Cent: return 19;
            etc...
        }
    }

    static double Value(this CoinType coinType)
    {
        switch (coinType)
        {
            case CoinType.Cent: return 1.0;
            etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the same as krowe offered

Comment: Look closer because it is absolutely not. Any of the other answers with reflection, collections, or your tuples enum in your original post are serious overkill.

Comment: yes, I see now. You created static class for mapping

Comment: Yes that was my point. I also implemented the static functions as extension methods so you can write code like `Cent.Value()` without the overhead of allocating instances of a wrapper class.